# How many months can I drive in the US with a UK driving licence?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, usa, driving

How many months can I drive in the US with a UK driving licence? I'm interested in particular in the states of Florida and New York.

I know that with an Italian driving licence it's 1 month for Florida and 3 months for New York. [Source](http://www.patente.it/attualita/guidare-negli-stati-uniti-quale-patente-serve?idc=2722) (in Italian).

I am wondering if it's different for a UK licence.

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference what country issued the license.  The only thing that really matters is whether you establish residency in that state.  You can drive on a foreign license for much longer if you're visiting or residing temporarily for a short time.

Comment: In my case I would stay for a couple of months in Florida and then move to New York and live there (and probably I won't need to drive there). You are saying that I won't have troubles driving in Florida after the first month?

Comment: If you maintain another residence elsewhere, yes.  If not, then you're most likely establishing residence in Florida for a short time, in which case you must get a Florida license within 30 days of establishing your residence there.

Comment: PS. According to this website in Florida I can use a foreign driving licence for up to 7 months.. https://www.flhsmv.gov/driver-licenses-id-cards/visiting-florida-faqs